# Replacing a 1.5 million row data set every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table that is populated with approximately 1.5 million rows of data that needs to be entirely refreshed every 5 minutes. The data is no longer needed once it is older than 5 minutes.

Getting the data into the table is no problem...I can populate it in approximately 50-70 seconds. Where I'm having some trouble is figuring out how to shift all the old data out and replace it with new data. I need to be able to run queries at any time across the entire data set. These queries need to run very fast and they must contain only data from one data set at a time (i.e., the query should not pull a combination of new and old data during the 1 minute that the table is being updated).

I do not have much experience working with large temporary data sets, so I would appreciate some advice on how best to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use `DELETE` statement, but @RolandStarke idea is good, it's probably faster to change the name of your table, create a new table, populate it with the new data, then drop the first one.

Comment: The DELETE approach would need to be within a transaction, meaning that the table would be locked for over a minute during the delete and reinsert. The DELETE would also be blocked during open reads.  The RENAME option can't even be within a transaction as its DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Create partitions. You can then populate one partition while users query from the other.

To do this manually you just need something like...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl0 (blah)
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (blah) 
CREATE TABLE meta (combined_source INT)
INSERT INTO meta VALUES (0)

CREATE VIEW combined AS
  SELECT * FROM tbl0 WHERE 0 = (SELECT combined_source FROM meta) % 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE 1 = (SELECT combined_source FROM meta) % 2
```

Now you can insert new data into the 'inactive' table and it WON'T appear in the view.

Next, increment the value in `meta`. Immediately the view switches from showing data from one table to showing data from the other table.

On your next iteration you just check `meta` to determine which table to empty and load the new data into.

One benefit of this approach is that you don't even need to be within a transaction.